# how to set datetime value as it is in sql using declare set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get the datetime value using getdate() query. it is working.

Now, have to set the value in the variable.

## Here my query is,

```
Declare @value datetime
set @value = (select getdate())
print @value
Go
```

## output

Mar 19 2014  3:42PM

But actual getdate() value is '2014-03-19 15:43:09.493'

Here, i want to store this value as it is too @value.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @value datetime
    SET @value = GetDate()

SELECT @value
```

Note that when printing the value it is converted to text, hence why it *appears* differently.

Your datatype is set to `datetime` so you're doing the right thing.

Comment: okay Mr. Thank you. my thought to store the value as it is. but here it is converting as text format as you said.